# Open source math editor

Tags: open-source, math, editor

Because the Math have many technical symbols.

In the MathOverflow site if we text the `$\sin^2 \theta$` we can get the

[image]

So, if there is a open source editor we can use?

Comment: TeXstudio allows to write mathematics and see it rendered after one key press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation you refer to originates in the [Latex](https://www.latex-project.org/) typesetting system which is open source. You might want to have a look into the various out-of-the-box solutions which exist for typesetting Latex documents. [Miktex](https://miktex.org/) is a good starting point.

Furthermore there are several [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown) editors supporting Latex math notation by means of Math Javascript libraries like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). [Marktext](https://marktext.app/) is a good starting point, but here is a [list](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/List-of-web-based-math-editors) of MathJax powered editors.